# Which Attributes Does Chrome Autofill Expect?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, autofill

I was hoping to tie our site in with Chrome's Address Autofill, but I can't find any reference for how it expects the forms to be presented.

I'm guessing it's looking for something pretty specific in the name= fields of the forms, but a good reference would be nice, instead of having to reverse engineer it.

At the moment, Chrome fills none of our forms, but Safari fills most of them. At the risk of asking two questions at once: anyone got a reference for safari as well? Safari seems to be using our title= fields...

It doesn't use this standard, does it? http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3106.txt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera

Comment: thanks for the tip. I did a bunch of searching, but didn't find this one. Still, it looks like it's the wild west out there.

Comment: @Alec: I think your best best it to look at Chromium's code directly, if that's really the only browser you want to target. See my answer.

Comment: @Alec: did that answer your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 8):

This question is pretty old but I have an **updated answer for 2017**!

**There is now *full documentation* on how to trigger autocomplete.**

[Here's a link to the official ***current WHATWG HTML Standard*** for enabling autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)

***The following answer is from my original answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965106/1696153***

Google wrote a [pretty nice guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values) for developing web applications that are friendly for mobile devices. They have a section on how to name the inputs on forms to easily use auto-fill. Eventhough it's written for mobile, this applies for both desktop and mobile!

## How to Enable AutoComplete on your HTML forms

Here are some key points on how to enable autocomplete:

- **Use a `<label>` for all your `<input>` fields**
- **Add a `autocomplete` attribute** to your `<input>` tags and fill it in using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).
- **Name your `name` and `autocomplete` attributes correctly for all `<input>` tags**
- ***Example***:

  ```
  <label for="frmNameA">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="frmNameA"
  placeholder="Full name" required autocomplete="name">

  <label for="frmEmailA">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <!-- note that "emailC" will not be autocompleted -->
  <label for="frmEmailC">Confirm Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="emailC" id="frmEmailC"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <label for="frmPhoneNumA">Phone</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="frmPhoneNumA"
  placeholder="+1-555-555-1212" required autocomplete="tel">
  ```

## How to name your `<input>` tags

In order to trigger autocomplete, make sure you correctly name the `name` and `autocomplete` attributes in your `<input>` tags. This will automatically allow for autocomplete on forms. Make sure also to have a `<label>`! This information can also be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).

Here's how to name your inputs:

- *Name*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `name fname mname lname`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `name` (for full name)
    - `given-name` (for first name)
    - `additional-name` (for middle name)
    - `family-name` (for last name)
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name">`
- *Email*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `email`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `email`
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="email">`
- *Address*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `address city region province state zip zip2 postal country`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - For one address input:

      - `street-address`
    - For two address inputs:

      - `address-line1`
      - `address-line2`
    - `address-level1` (state or province)
    - `address-level2` (city)
    - `postal-code` (zip code)
    - `country`
- *Phone*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `phone mobile country-code area-code exchange suffix ext`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `tel`
- *Credit Card*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `ccname cardnumber cvc ccmonth ccyear exp-date card-type`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `cc-name`
    - `cc-number`
    - `cc-csc`
    - `cc-exp-month`
    - `cc-exp-year`
    - `cc-exp`
    - `cc-type`
- *Usernames*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `username`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `username`
- *Passwords*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `password`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `current-password` (for sign-in forms)
    - `new-password` (for sign-up and password-change forms)

## Resources

- [Current WHATWG HTML Standard for autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)
- ["Create Amazing Forms" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values). Seems to be updated almost daily. Excellent read.
- ["Help Users Checkout Faster with Autofill" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) in 2015.

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41965106/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of stuff that could be "expected" (like things in [RFC3106](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3106.txt) or the [hCard format](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-input-formats)) but in the end it comes down to what you can find in the [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) [source](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc) [code](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code), I guess.

This specific section which seems to be [Chromium's AutoFill implementation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/autofill_regex_constants.h&q=autofill_regex_constan&sq=package%3achromium&l=5) is probably of interest for you, which I found by using the [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/) feature [for Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch) now available via [Google Code Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/).

Some of the [constants are extern-ed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch) used for regular expressions are defined in `autofill_regex_constants.h` and provided in a fairly [extensive list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/autofill_regex_constants.cc.utf8&sq=package%3achromium) (even with I18N support!) in `autofill_regex_constants.cc.utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome (v51.0) implements the following spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill

This means that you can populate the `autocomplete` attribute with specific types of values that Chrome should fill in.

**Examples:**

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="address-line1" id="a1" name="a1" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="address-line2" id="a2" name="a2" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="address-level2" id="city" name="city" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="address-level1" id="state" name="state" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="country-name" id="country" name="country" />

<input type="text" autocomplete="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="email" id="email" name="email" />
```

(Obviously I've left out the labels on the examples)