# Input names for separate birthday-fields - Autofill

Tags: html, forms, autofill

we have a large form with 3 separate fields for birthday (year, month, day).

To make autofill (f.e. on iOS) work, you have to use specific names on the fields.

According to RFC 3106 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3106) there are separate names available for Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Day, Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Month and Eom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Year, but I cannot find the correct values for birthday-fields.

If we'd have a general field for the whole date, it would be "birthday", according to [Form field names used by personal data auto-fill in browsers (Safari, Opera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera)

Thanks
Raphael

Answer (score 4):

The [description of `autocomplete`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls%3a-the-autocomplete-attribute) in the August 2013 version of HTML5 CR contained a list of suggested form field names. It was dropped in the next version, partly because it had not been implemented in browsers. But it might be re-introduced in a later version, and it’s still [part](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofilling-form-controls%3a-the-autocomplete-attribute) of the “WHATWG Living HTML Standard”. So it’s probably the best guess if you wish to use names that might some day become standard. In it, the fields would be `bday-year`, `bday-month`, and `bday-day` (with all-numeric values).

Answer (score 1):

[According to the MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete):

**"bday"**

A birth date, as a full date.

---

*or*

**"bday-day"**

The day of the month of a birth date.

---

**"bday-month"**

The month of the year of a birth date.

---

**"bday-year"**
The year of a birth date.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 3106 is only for E-Commerce, you won't get the Personal detail ones there.

---

According to  [Safari AutoFills](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070527063904285)  the file Contents/Resources/English.lproj/ABAutoCompleteMappings.plist within the Safari.app package
there are 3 fields for birthday:

```
birthday
date of birth
born
```

You can find the suitable one for yourself.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, these are still names for the complete birthday and not for separate fields.
I expected something like "birthday_year" "birthday_month" and "birthday_day"...