# How to get autofill for Safari for last name/family-name fields?

Tags: html, ios, safari, autofill

I have troubles getting autofill work for iOS Safari browser in a form where name is parted up into first and last name.

I have tried with this simple example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. John" autocomplete="given-name" name="firstName">
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Doe" autocomplete="family-name" name="lastName">
```

But that only suggest to autofill the firstname.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/simplenotezy-the-looper/pen/PoOoqjx

Options I've tried for `autocomplete=""`:

- family-name
- surname
- lastname
- last-name
- lname
- last name

I've also tried changing the `name=""` field to names from above list to no avail.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027462/form-field-names-used-by-personal-data-auto-fill-in-browsers-safari-opera) help you ?

Comment: @PtitXav thanks for sharing - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

It's disabled by default, you must enable it in your iOS settings

See https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/automatically-fill-in-forms-iphccfb450b7/ios